# How to use a function for each row of a dataframe - .apply? .map .mask?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I often need to apply 'by row' logic to a dataframe and though i might have a function to do it, i'm not sure how to apply it to the dataframe rather than rely on a for loop.

The below code works, but it seems like it isn't he best way of doing it. I tried putting it into functions and using lambda, .apply and .map, but whatever i'm doing i'm not putting it together correctly. I've tried reading around this, but can't get by head around whether i'm trying to apply to a dataframe, a series, element-wise etc in a actual example like below.

For example look at this dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import random

example = pd.DataFrame({'Total Completions(2015)': [0,0,0,5,10,0],
                      'Total Completions(2016)': [0,1,4,0,18,0],
                      'Total Completions(2017)': [2,1,6,5,0,15],
                      'Total Completions(2018)': [0,0,8,5,0,1]})
```

What i want to do is to find the first year that has completions in it (>0). The first bit of code identifies which columns are the total columns and picks out the relevant year from between the brackets. It then finds which of these possible years is the earliest with any completions in it (>0) and uses this as the minimum year in which to do the next part - assign a random date in that financial year.

```
# initiates the columns i want to populate to start
example['min_yr'] = 0
example['Dummy Date'] = ''

# gets the first year where completions begin

for row in example.index:
    min_yr = 0
    for header in example.columns:
        # if it's one of the total columns
        if header[:5] == 'Total':
            # get the year as an integer from the brackets in the header
            get_yr = int(header[18:-1])
            # if it's the first year with completions it comes across, that year is first minimum
            if min_yr == 0 and example[header][row] > 0:
                min_yr = get_yr
            # if there is already a min year but there is a new year with an entry that's earlier
            # replace with the new minimum year
            elif min_yr > 0 and example[header][row] > 0 and get_yr < min_yr:
                min_yr = get_yr
    example['min_yr'][row] = min_yr
```

I then assign the random year based on the min year i just found:

```
for row in example.index:
    start_date = datetime.date((example['min_yr'][row] -1), 4, 1)
    end_date = datetime.date(example['min_yr'][row], 3, 31)

    time_between_dates = end_date - start_date
    days_between_dates = time_between_dates.days
    random_number_of_days = random.randrange(days_between_dates)
    random_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=random_number_of_days)
    example['Dummy Date'][row] = random_date
```

So in these examples, am i applying to a dataframe or a series, and how do i structure the argument?

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `example.apply(lambda x: x.gt(0).idxmax(axis=1), axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[1]).str.rstrip(')')`

Comment: That's a bit beyond me to unpick unfortunately. Though i can see the split part might be useful - had forgotten about that. I'll try and puzzle through it later if i can. I was generally talking about making my own functions and applying them to the data (generally lists of columns used to calculate something, to populate another column)

Comment: You can try this on your input dataframe and walk step by step to see how apply is working.